# Prove that sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(x_{n})$ be sequence in metric space $(X,d)$. Prove that if $c_{n}=d(x_{1},x_{2})+d(x_{2},x_{3})+...+d(x_{n},x_{n+1})$ is bounded then $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy.

I'm not sure if my proof is correct. I would greatly appreciate help.

Proof: We know that $d(a,b) \geqslant 0$, so $c_{n}$ is increasing. We know that bounded and increasing sequence is convergent, so series $\sum d(x_{n},x_{n+1})$ is convergent. That implies that, $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_{n},x_{n+1})=0$ so sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: bounded and increasing is convergent only holds in a complete metric space, the whole idea of cauchy sequences is they can also approach "holes" in your space.  Like if you have rational numbers that approach the square root of 2

Comment: "$\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,x_{n+1})=0$ so sequence is Cauchy": no. The beginning of your proof is correct but you have to modify your last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  You need to show that given any $\epsilon>0$ there is some number $N$ such that for all numbers bigger than that, $n,m>N$  you have $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$.   Use the triangle inequality to compare the distance to the sequential distance,  then assume for sake of contradiction that it is not cauchy,  so you have some $\epsilon$ that no such $N$ exists.  Use that to contradict $c_n$ is bounded

Comment: I'll ask to be sure if I understand correctly. From the assumption that it's not Cauchy we can find infinitely many such pairs $ m, n $ that $ d (x_ {m}, x_ {n})> \epsilon $ and adding them toghether we would get that $ c_ {n} $  is not bounded.

Comment: Yep,  that's the ticket